# How can I configure a CheckPoint SSL vpn?

Tags: 11.10, 64-bit, vpn

I have a brand new laptop (yay!) running 64bit Oneiric Ocelot and I'm still figuring out the pieces missing from my old 32bit system. I need to connect to a CheckPoint SSL vpn at work, but there seems to be no official client for 64bit linux.

From the looks of it it's a simple SSL tunnel of some kind, but I have no details. On my old system I used to run [the SNX software](https://supportcenter.checkpoint.com/supportcenter/portal/user/anon/page/default.psml/media-type/html?action=portlets.DCFileAction&eventSubmit_doGetdcdetails=&fileid=8993) but there's no 64bit version available, so I'm looking for options.

Is there a compatible software? Can I somehow run the 32bit client? Can I configure the VPN using the usual system tools?

For what it's worth I've been able to run the old snx client inside a 32 bit chroot jail, following for the most part the instructions at [ubuntuforums.org](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=24575). You can skip the parts about mounting filesystems in the chroot environment, but you'll need to install a 32 bit kernel, libX6 and libstdc++5 inside the chrooted environment.

Comment: For what it's worth I've been able to run the old snx client inside a 32 bit chroot jail, following for the most part the instructions at [ubuntuforums.org](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=24575). You can skip the parts about mounting filesystems in the chroot environment, but you'll need to install a 32 bit kernel, libX6 and libstdc++5 inside the chrooted environment.